# How can I call the javascript plugin

Tags: theming, 8, plugins

How can I call a JAVASCRIPT plugin in Twig template?
I try to use something like this code in my `html.html.twig` template, but it seems that this not work correctly:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Is there any difference between html and twig?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Any downvoter can explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it properly in a file (the plugin initialisation), add the file via a library, then load the library in the template file using twig:

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/mylibraryname') }}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets